# Changing memory value of a unmanaged code in a managed code

Tags: c#, memory

How to change memory value of a unmanaged code in a managed code, I'm creating a hack for a game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinvoke using [WriteProcessMemory()](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/WriteProcessMemory.html).